# how to upload image file from ImageView to nodejs server (multer) using okhttp? Kotlin

Tags: android, node.js, kotlin, multer, okhttp

I have written code to upload images to the server using okhttp and kotlin, that is, the user takes a picture through the camera then displays the image in the imageView when the user clicks the send button, I want the image from ImageView to be sent to the server, but I don't know how to change the image from ImageView be a file that can be sent to the server, please see my code for more details

this is my kotlin code

```
 fun uploadImage(url:String, image:File, imageName:String){
    val MEDIA_TYPE_PNG = MediaType.parse("image/png")
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormDataPart("file", imageName, RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_PNG, image))
        .build()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .post(requestBody)
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object:Callback{
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            Log.i(TAG,"response ${response.body?.string()}")
        }
    })
}
```

the question is, how to convert image from imageView to "image:File" for uploadImage function?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
    val url = getString(R.string.urlUpload)
    val MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG = MediaType.parse("image/jpeg")

    val bitmap = (img_register.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
      val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
   val bitmapByteArray = baos.toByteArray()
  val file = Base64.encodeToString(bitmapByteArray,Base64.DEFAULT)
```